# Make app's alertdialogs look like Play Services Location Enable dialog?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-alertdialog

I switched to using Google Play Services `SettingsApi` to allow users to turn on location from inside the app if required.
However, I would like all similar alerts in my app, e.g. bluetooth, to look like the location dialog shown by play services.

Does anyone know how to do that ? I tried setting different themes on my AlertDialogs but I can't get it to match the Theme for Play Services' dialog across device e.g. if it matches on a Lollipop devices, it doesn't match on a KitKat device and vice versa.

For e.g. the Play Services 7.0.0 location dialog on an S4 looks like this:

[image: Play Services Dialog]

And a standard alert dialog looks like this:

[image: Custom dialog]

The code for the alert dialog is:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Alert Title")
                .setMessage("Alert Message")
                .setPositiveButton("Enabled", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create().show();
```

How can I make my custom dialog look similar to the Play Services one ?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: try AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog)

Comment: Tried it but then it's not the same on Lollipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android resource was designed exactly for such kind of tasks -- helping you select the most suitable resources based on your environment, such as device type, user language, platform version, etc. If you use resource file to specify your dialog style, you don't need to write your own code to check for platform versions yourself.

First, create a default `style.xml` under `res/values` directory to handle those Android versions before Honeycomb, which use `Theme.Holo.Dialog` theme:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
  </style>
</resources>
```

For Android versions between Honeycomb and KitKat, you need `Theme.Holo.Panel`. This `styles.xml` should be located at `res/values-v11`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Panel">
  </style>
</resources>
```

And at last, a Materialized style file under `res/values-v21`, for Lollipop and later Android versions:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Panel">
  </style>
</resources>
```

After that, you just need to specify `MyThemeSelector` as your dialog style when creating your `AlertDialog`. Happy Hacking!

Comment: Ah... I think the Panel thing is what I might have been missing. I'll check soon and respond.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to check for Build versions and setting my alert's style based on that after a lot of experimentation.

It seems Google's dialog does not use any standard Android style. Everything from Material to Holo to DeviceDefault fails on different versions.